# In C++, why can I call vector<double>::begin() in for a private content in a class?

Tags: c++, class

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class AAA {
private:
    vector<double> v;

public:
    AAA(int n);
    void AAAprint();
    void testfn(AAA &aaa);
};

AAA::AAA(int n){
    v=vector<double>(n,0);
}

void AAA::AAAprint(){
    for (int i=0;(unsigned int) i<v.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

void AAA::testfn(AAA &aaa)
{
     aaa.v[0]=5;
}

int main(){
    AAA aaa(25);
    aaa.AAAprint();
    AAA bbb(25);
    bbb.testfn(aaa);
    aaa.AAAprint();
}
```

In main i first construct aaa then print out its value. Next `aaa` is changed after calling `bbb.testfn(aaa)`. In `void AAA::testfn()`, I could directly access to `aaa.v` and the value of `aaa.v[0]` is indeed changed outside of `void AAA::testfn()`. Since I printout aaa.v in the end of main function it shows so. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @JohnKugelman It has been updated.

Comment: Well, are you calling from the scope of class `AAA`?

Comment: @aschepler Yes.

Comment: Is your question why can you access privates of `AAA` within `class AAA`, or why you can pass `a.v.begin()` as a `double*`?

Comment: @Tas That is my question. I could do it without causing any error or warning. And the numerics are correct (in my own code those numbers are not as simple as 0).

Comment: _Which_ is your question, or are you asking both?

Comment: @Tas My question is: why can I use v.begin() outside of the class and meanwhile change the value corresponding to v.begin() ?

Comment: I wish I could downvote this more than just once. You have to actually post your code, not stuff you made up that bears a slight resemblance to your real code.

Comment: @Resorter [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/lTbYC0).  Compiler error shows up, just as expected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have uploaded a complete example. Sorry for the confusion in the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privcy is a class restriction not an instance restriction.  All instances of a class have full access to private members of all other instances.

There are quirks about inheritance and protected and distinct instances, but that is another question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.